# AWS Config: Custom rule for required-tags says "no tags" even when "Name" tag exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have customised the managed rule - required-tags and modified the lambda function to extend upto 9 tags and more.

The code seems to work and gives me the expected result.

This rule checks for tags given in "Rule Parameters". Empty and partially tagged are non compliant; fully tagged are compliant.

The problem I face is when a new EC2 instance is created and the custom rule triggers with configuration changes gives me "no tags" even when "name" tag is present.

When I re-evaluate for the second time, the expected result is got (missing tags except name tag)

The condition goes like this

```
if evaluation["compliance_type"] == "NON_COMPLIANT":
        print ("NON_COMPLIANT")
        if len(evaluation["current_tags"]) > 0:
            print ("Non zero tags")
            // evaluation report      
        else:
            print ("Zero tags")
            // evaluation report
```

EC2 instance was laucnhed around 12:39 PM

Cloudwatch logs after automatic trigger(configuration changes) around 12:41 PM

```
{
    'current_tags': [], 
    'compliance_type': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 
    'annotation': 'Name, Customer, Environment, etc not present'
}
```

Cloudwatch logs after manual re-evaluation around 12:43 PM

```
{
    'current_tags': [{u'value': u'instance_name', u'key': u'Name'}],
    'compliance_type': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 
    'annotation': 'Customer, Environment, etc not present'
}
```

The event payload passed to lambda function (trigger: configuration changes) at instance creation time has `current_tags: empty` (even though name tag is added during instance creation; exists). Is there a way to find out how and when the tags gets added to the instance. Or the trigger can be delayed (not periodic trigger)